# Adjusted Survival Curves in R From Cox Model at Specific Covariate Values

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'd like to plot adjusted survival curves from a Cox model at specific covariate values. The `survfit` function in the `survival` package and `ggsurvplot` in `survminer` allow one to easily plot adjusted survival curves from a model, but seem to only do so at mean values of covariates. I would like to plot curves at values that I specify, but can't find a way to easily do this in `R`. `SAS`can do this easily by using the `BASELINE`command in `PROC PHREG`and I'm looking to be able to do something like this in `R`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this "by hand".  Here is one possibility using the example data from `coxph()`.  Essentially, you need to make a dataset that holds constant all model variables at values you want to use and then vary time from the minimum to maximum in the data (here 0:4).  Then, you can predict the survival probabilities for these data and plot.

```r
  library(ggplot2)
  library(survival)
  test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 
# Fit a stratified model 
m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1) 

tmp1 <- data.frame(
  time = 0:4, 
  status=0, 
  x = 1, 
  sex = 0)

tmp1$fit <- predict(m1, newdata=tmp1, type="survival")

ggplot(tmp1, aes(x=time, y=fit)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Below, we pick a different value of `x`, generate predictions and put the data together with the prediction data above.  This could be done in a single step if you wanted.

```r
tmp2 <- data.frame(
  time = 0:4, 
  status=0, 
  x = 2, 
  sex = 0)

tmp2$fit <- predict(m1, newdata=tmp2, type="survival")

tmp <- rbind(tmp1, tmp2)
```

Now, we could plot both sets of predictions on the same plot.

```r
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=time, y=fit, colour=as.factor(x))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(colour="X")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>